# Can't figure out how to dynamically change custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview. when te listview is called i want it to load all the profiles from my database, this works. but i also want to check the status of the profile and depending of the result i want to show a certain icon next to it. but i cant seem to figure out how to get this done properly.. this is what i have so far:

profiles_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menuBtn"
        android:background="#2cffffff">
    </ListView>
<RelativeLayout/>
```

list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statusIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
    public class ProfilesList extends CredenceOneActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

            static final int STATUS_SUCCES =1;
            static final int STATUS_WARNING =2;
            static final int STATUS_ERROR =3;

            private ListView list;
            private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

            private DB_Handler db;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
                    setContentView(R.layout.profiles_list);
                }
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    db = new DB_Handler(this);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  


            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
            // Here, you set the data in your ListView
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            loadRegisteredProfiles();
       }

    public void loadRegisteredProfiles() {
        List<DB_Profiles> storedProfiles = db.getAllProfiles();
        for (DB_Profiles profile : storedProfiles) {
            String name= profile.getNAME();
            arrayList.add(name);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

i want to do something like this for each profile that is loaded in the listview:

```
DB_Profiles profile;
if (profile.getStatus==STATUS_SUCCES{
statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.succes);}
else{profile.getStatus==STATUS_ERROR{
statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);}}
        }
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to create your **custom adapter**, currently you are using `ArrayAdapter`, you are not even using the list row layout `list_layout.xml` anywhere in the code, right?

Comment: Yazan is right. Please refer this link: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **getView()** of the listview's adapter, you can use the **setImageResource()** of the **imageView**, in your list_item layout.

Comment: OP is not using a custom adapter, nor a custom list row layout.

Answer (score 2):

In the getView() of your Custom Adapter write the below piece of code.

```
   ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowLayout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imagView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (profile.getStatus==STATUS_SUCCES)
        {
                 holder.imagView.setImageResource(R.drawable.succes);
        }
    else if(profile.getStatus==STATUS_ERROR)
        {
                holder.imagView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
         }

    return convertView;
```

And declare static inner class in your custom adapter, like this

```
       static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView img;

}
```